# generic std-like chrono-independent template stopwatch

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, generic-programming

I had a simple stopwatch class that was basically using `std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - this->start_` in its implementation for measuring elapsed time.
I have decided to upgrade it and make fully generic, std-compliant, not depending on a particular clock type, so user can specify his own clock type.
I also had a template `stopwatch::operator DurationType() const` for convenience, to convert to a specific duration type, for instance:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds msecs = stopwatch;
```

But there is one problem: I can't get rid of a `chrono` header since I am using its `duration_cast`.

I have come up with 2 ideas. One of them works but not very convenient, and the other does not work at all and is pretty ugly.

```
// stopwatch.h
#pragma once

// #include <chrono>

namespace eld
{
    template <typename ClockType,
            typename DurationCaster>
    class stopwatch
    {
    public:

        using clock_type = ClockType;
        using duration = typename clock_type::duration;

        stopwatch()
             : start_(clock_type::now())
        {}

        void reset()
        {
            start_ = clock_type::now();
        }

        typename clock_type::duration result() const
        {
            return clock_type::now() - start_;
        }

        template<typename Duration>
        Duration result() const
        {
            // return std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(result()); // TODO: remove this
            return DurationCaster()(Duration(), result());
        }

        template<typename Duration>
        operator Duration() const
        {
            return result<Duration>();
        }

        // This is ugly and does not work
//        template <typename Caster>
//        auto operator()(Caster caster) -> decltype(Caster::operator()(typename clock_type::time_point))
//        {
//            return caster(result());
//        }

    private:
        typename clock_type::time_point start_;
    };

}
```

```
// dummy.cpp

#include <stopwatch/stopwatch.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

// this is inconvenient
struct DurationCaster
{
    template<typename ToDuration, typename FromDuration>
    constexpr ToDuration operator()(ToDuration, FromDuration fromDuration) const
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<ToDuration>(fromDuration);
    }
};

int main()
{

    eld::stopwatch<std::chrono::steady_clock, DurationCaster> steadyWatch{};

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));

    std::chrono::nanoseconds nanoseconds = steadyWatch.result();
    std::cout << nanoseconds.count() << std::endl;

    std::chrono::milliseconds milliseconds = steadyWatch;
    std::cout << milliseconds.count() << std::endl;

    // This is ugly and does not work
//    milliseconds = steadyWatch([](typename decltype(steadyWatch)::duration from)
//            {
//        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(from);
//            });

    return 0;
}
```

Whilst the first option works despite its inconvenience, I want to know if I can get rid of `std::chrono::duration_cast` in my header in a more elegant way.
Or is this as good as it gets?

P.S.: What's wrong with my second approach? Why can't I compile it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use first approach, maybe pass DurationCaster as argument to constructor, then it can be possible to use functions and not only functional-objects? And also you don't need to create `DurationCaster` every time in `operator()`, do it once.
Or, you can use default `DurationCaster`, which uses `duration_cast` under the hood, define like `typename DurationCaster = your_default_caster`

About why not working second: as i can see here is an error in `decltype(Caster::operator()(typename clock_type::time_point))`, you refer to `operator` as static member function, it's wrong.

This should work:

```cpp
template <typename Caster>
auto operator()(Caster caster) -> typename std::result_of<Caster(typename clock_type::duration)>::type
{
    return caster(result());
}
```

PS: i know `result_of` is deprecated, but question is about cpp11